# jquery date picker

Tags: jquery-ui

just wondering is there a way to disable all the weekends in the jquery date picker?

Answer (score 1):

Do you not want them to be clickable or do you just want to not display them?

The following will hide them:

```
$("#yourDatePicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

If you still want to display the weekends, just not let them be selectable, you can use the `beforeShowDay`. This will check each day to see if it is a Sunday or Saturday, and if it is, returns false so that it will be disabled.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#myDatePicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableWeekends
  });

  function disableWeekends(date) {
    var daysToDisable = [0, 6];
    var day = date.getDay();
    for (i = 0; i < daysToDisable.length; i++) {
      if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
      }
    }
    return [true];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just having a quick look at the documentation, best guess would be to use the [beforeShowDay](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) event to disable the days you don't want to be selectable.

Answer (score 1):

use "$("#datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });" (change the id selector to match your field).